# How do I concatenate integers with lists in Python?

Tags: python

I have a python script that creates lists of numbers and I add some of those numbers together as integers.

```
ddtricks = [deal.dd_tricks("4SN"), \
            deal.dd_tricks("5HE"),deal.dd_tricks("5DE"),deal.dd_tricks("5CE"), \
            deal.dd_tricks("5HW"),deal.dd_tricks("5DW"),deal.dd_tricks("5CW") ]
   
ddscores = [deal.dd_score("4SN", NS_Vul), \
            deal.dd_score("5HW", EW_Vul), deal.dd_score("5DE", EW_Vul), deal.dd_score("5CW", EW_Vul), \      
            deal.dd_score("5HE", EW_Vul), deal.dd_score("5DW", EW_Vul), deal.dd_score("5CE", EW_Vul)]
                        
                    
TotNSScore = TotNSScore + deal.dd_score("4SN", NS_Vul)
MaxEWScore = max(deal.dd_score("5HW", EW_Vul), deal.dd_score("5DE", EW_Vul), deal.dd_score("5CW", EW_Vul), \
                 deal.dd_score("5HE", EW_Vul), deal.dd_score("5DW", EW_Vul), deal.dd_score("5CE", EW_Vul))
TotEWScore = TotEWScore + MaxEWScore
```

Then I want to print those out together:

```
outputlist = ddtricks+ddscores+MaxEWScore+Bid4SGood
for x in outputlist :
    f.write(str(x)+", ")
f.write("\n")
```

Creating outputlist gives this error: "outputlist = ddtricks+ddscores+MaxEWScore+Bid4SGood
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list"

If I make TotEWScore and MaxEWScore lists, I don't think I can add them together and get the arithmetic sum.  And I can't find anything that allows me to type cast those variables as a list to allow concatenation.

I'm pretty new to python. Programming experience mainly in Fortran and pascal, so data structures like lists are foreign to me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `outputlist = ddtricks+ddscores+[MaxEWScore]+[Bid4SGood]`

Answer (score 0):

You can either wrap them in a list to concatenate them with other lists:

```
outputlist = ddtricks + ddscores + [MaxEWScore, Bid4SGood]
```

or use spread syntax for the existing lists:

```
outputlist = [*ddtricks, *ddscores, MaxEWScore, Bid4SGood]
```

And when you're writing to the file, you can use `join()` instead of a loop:

```
f.write(", ".join(outputlist) + "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about spread or join. Good to know.